# select rows between two character values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which shows as below:

```
S.No   | Action
1      |   New
2      |   Dependent
3      |   Dependent
4      |   Dependent
5      |   New
6      |   Dependent
7      |   Dependent
8      |   New
9      |   Dependent
10     |   Dependent
```

I here want to select the rows between the first two 'New' values in the Action column, including the first row with the 'New' action. Like [New,New)

For example:
In this case, I want to select rows 1,2,3,4.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm.  Let's count up the cumulative number of times that `New` appears as a value and use that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when action = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by s_no) as cume_new
      from t
     ) t
where cume_new = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do some magic with analytic functions 
1 select group of NEW actions, to get min and max s_no
2 select lead of 2 rows
3 select get between 2 sno (min and max)

```
with t as (
select 1 sno, 'New' action from dual union
select 2,'Dependent' from dual union
select 3,'Dependent' from dual union
select 4,'Dependent' from dual union
select 5,'New' from dual union
select 6,'Dependent' from dual union
select 7,'Dependent' from dual union
select 8,'New' from dual union
select 9,'Dependent' from dual union
select 10,'Dependent' from dual
)
select * 
  from (select * 
          from (select sno, lead(sno) over (order by sno) a 
                  from ( select row_number() over (partition by action order by Sno) t,
                                t.sno
                           from t
                          where t.action = 'New'
                        ) a 
                 where t <=2 ) 
         where a is not null) a, t 
 where t.sno >= a.sno and t.sno < a.a
```